# Is there a way to categorize technical words by their primary domain of usage

Tags: nlp

I have a very comprehensive list of technical words that I need to sort into broad categories like physics, chemistry, medicine, etc (I realize that these categories might overlap, which is ok). The words are very obscure and so no listed in many dictionaries (i.e. "microcrith"). I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: Suggestion: Query a search engine with the words in question, retrieve multiple matching documents, classify the documents.

Comment: @qqilihq a very good approach

Comment: @qqilihq that's a great idea but I need to do this for tens of thousands of words. Google might block me after a while!

Comment: You can try downloading wikipedia and see on what pages the words appear. There's everything in wikipedia and you already have the categories. For instance, microcrith appears in wictionary with category physics.